# programmatically selected option is not highlighted in ui-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select2, ui-select

angular version: AngularJS v1.3.6
http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select : Version: 0.8.3

var p1 = { name: 'Ramesh',      email: 'Ramesh@email.com',      age: 99 };

```
   $scope.people = [
            { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12 },
            { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30 },
            { name: 'Samantha',  email: 'samantha@email.com',  age: 31 },
            { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefanía@email.com', age: 16 },
            { name: 'Natasha',   email: 'natasha@email.com',   age: 54 },               
            { name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21 },
            p1
        ];

 $scope.people.selected = p1 ;
```

**html**:

```html
  <ui-select  class="full-width-select select" ng-model="people.selected" theme="select2">
                <ui-select-match  allow-clear="false">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | filter:$select.search">
                    <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
```

**Issue is When p1 is selected programatically the**

**p1 object is not highlighted in the ui-select drop down.**

Output is:

[image]

http://plnkr.co/edit/3mrECwGJbz2UYcrDiCha?p=preview

[image]

Comment: AngularJS version? Tried it and worked. Can you show your HTML?

Comment: Can you try to replicate it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/3ZQfh4S0KOA9EQm1NS7b?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/3mrECwGJbz2UYcrDiCha?p=preview   , click on button select Ramesh or Select John , and if you click on the select dropdown the option in the dropdown "ramesh or john" should get highlighted

Comment: Yep , It is working fine , but i suggest switch to new ui-select version is better approch

Comment: Good :) Please accept the answer to mark the question as answered, or if you feel the answer was not enough, provide one yourself. As long as it will not remain as unsolved :)

Comment: How did you solve this with the new version @praveenpds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the following change in AngularJS **1.3.1**:

```
$observe: check if the attribute is undefined
```

Ui-select uses `$observe` to set a default value for `resetSearchInput`:

```
attrs.$observe('resetSearchInput', function() {
  var resetSearchInput = scope.$eval(attrs.resetSearchInput);
  $select.resetSearchInput = resetSearchInput !== undefined ? resetSearchInput : true;
});
```

But since the change noted above and since `resetSearchInput` is undefined, the observer function will never get executed.

To solve it for now add the following attribute to your ui-select element:

```
reset-search-input="'false'"
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/M0pXrN3n6CBjjoJXS4df?p=preview

Comment: but your Plunk works fine even without the reset-search-input attribute? plnkr.co/edit/RlRH7T

Comment: @waxingsatirical If you click the "Select Ramesh" button then open the drop down, Ramesh isn't highlighted. At least not for me.